# How can I run a docker container from a docker image from docker hub in skaffold?

Tags: skaffold

Let's say I want to run a container from an image from docker hub, let's say [mosquitto](https://hub.docker.com/_/eclipse-mosquitto) I'd execute `docker run -it -p 1883:1883 -p 9001:9001 eclipse-mosquitto`.

I tried to pull the image from gcr.io (`deployment.yaml`) like done [here](https://github.com/james-vutiliti/chirpstack-kubernetes/blob/d5d398d3871429a3623d043a5dd546d01a5aead8/k8s/mqtt/mosquitto-deployment.yaml#L27):

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: mqtt-broker
  labels:
    app: mqtt-broker
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
    - targetPort: 1883
      port: 1883
  selector:
    app: mqtt-broker
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: mqtt-broker
  labels:
    app: mqtt-broker
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: mqtt-broker
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: mqtt-broker
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: mqtt-broker
        image: gcr.io/vu-james-celli/eclipse-mosquitto  # https://hub.docker.com/_/eclipse-mosquitto
        ports:
        - containerPort: 1883
```

`skaffold.yaml`:

```yaml
apiVersion: skaffold/v2beta10
kind: Config
build:
  artifacts:
  - <other image builds>
deploy:
  kubectl:
    manifests:
      - mqtt-broker/*
portForward:
  - resourceType: deployment
    resourceName: mqtt-broker
    port: 1883
    localPort: 1883
  <other port forwardings>
...
```

However when I run `skaffold --dev --port-forward` I get an error in the output:

```
- deployment/mqtt-broker: container mqtt-broker is waiting to start: gcr.io/vu-james-celli/eclipse-mosquitto can't be pulled
```

How do I have to configure `skaffold.yaml` ([schema version v2beta10](https://skaffold.dev/docs/references/yaml/?version=v2beta10)) when using `kubectl` to run the mosquitto container as part of a deployment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, pull the image from docker hub onto the local machine: `docker pull eclipse-mosquitto`

Second, refer the image in the `mqtt-broker/deployment.yaml` e.g.:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: mqtt-broker
  labels:
    app: mqtt-broker
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
    - targetPort: 1883
      port: 1883
  selector:
    app: mqtt-broker
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: mqtt-broker
  labels:
    app: mqtt-broker
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: mqtt-broker
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: mqtt-broker
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: mqtt-broker
        image: eclipse-mosquitto
        ports:
        - containerPort: 1883
```

Third, reference the `deploment.yaml in` skaffold.yaml` e.g.:

```yaml
apiVersion: skaffold/v2beta10
kind: Config
build:
  artifacts:
  - <services-under-development>
deploy:
  kubectl:
    manifests:
      - mqtt-broker/deployment.yaml
portForward:
  - resourceType: deployment
    resourceName: mqtt-broker
    port: 1883
    localPort: 1883
  - <port-forwarding-for-services-under-development>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could create a pod with a single container referencing `eclipse-mosquitto`, and then ensure that pod is referenced from your `skaffold.yaml`.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: mqtt
spec:
  containers:
  - name: mqtt
    image: eclipse-mosquitto
    ports:
    - containerPort: 1883
      name: mqtt
    - containerPort: 9001
      name: websockets
```

You could turn this into a deployment or replicaset with services, etc.

Comment: It's not clear to me how `skaffold` knows about that an `image` needs to be pulled from docker hub.

Comment: @brian-de-silva I added my cunnrent config and error output to the question.

Comment: Skaffold submits the pod definition, as specified in a kubernetes manifest referenced from your `skaffold.yaml`, to your Kubernetes cluster and the cluster pulls the image.